# How did software engineers test their code in 19xx?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, history, test-coverage

There is a plethora of tools available for engineers to test their code these days. However, frameworks like Mocha.js came around only in 2011 with the ascent of NPM. So I wonder what were the practices around software design a few decades ago?

Comment: There were frameworks and tools long before Mocha. E.g. I know that the Perl language came with unit tests in the TAP format in the late 80s, but it hardly was the first. Cyclomatic complexity was developed by McCabe in the mid-70s to enable comprehensive white box testing, but that too builds on older ideas.

Comment: Run system tests on a complete representative system.  If it doesn't work, use a debugger to find the problem.  Or roll your own test harnesses - create simple executables that call different bits the code under test.

Comment: 19xx is a very vague timeframe, spanning from the beginning of computers (mid-40s) which were programmed by adjusting cables on a big switch board, all the way to "not that different from what we do now" in the 90s. In 1995 CPAN went online, which is to Perl what NPM is to JavaScript. And even test-driven development is from the previous century, even though it reached high visibility only at the beginning of this one.

Comment: I've seen assert() used as a simple unit test

Comment: What makes you believe testing requires a framework or a tool? Frameworks and tools make testing more efficient, but it is pretty obvious that they are not mandatory.

Comment: If you're asking specifically about JavaScript testing, note that there really weren't many significant JavaScript applications written much before 2000/2001 in any case. JavaScript only really became useful with the launch of XMLHttpRequest (which slowly began deployment in 1999) and ES3 (which wasn't implementee in browsers until late 2000). As far as I'm aware, the first JavaScript unit testing framework was jsunit, which launched in 2001, and was essentially a direct port of junit. Before that there probably wasn't much need for such a framework.

Comment: We made our own tools. They are not very difficult to create.

Answer (score 3):

In the really early days, (mainframe & batch jobs days), testing was accomplished by the systems engineers writing a set of test data that they had hand calculated the results of but only gave a small sub-set of to the programmers. The programmers wrote the code and the test suites were run against the program and the output passed to the systems guys who passed back pass/fail results.

Of course we were also using static analysis tools such as [lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)), *(in Unix from 1979),* to spot areas needing specific attention.

A little later, when programmers had direct access to some hardware, we would write your own test harnesses & stubs to test our own code. Some teams had a process whereby developers tested each others code and for some projects where many sub-processes had common interfaces a generic test harness might be implemented to allow standardisation of testing and save the time of every developer creating their own test skeleton for each process, *I have done this myself on more than one team.*

In the late 19xxs they, *we*, were were using test frameworks such as [LDRA Testbed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDRA_Testbed), *(founded 1975)* & IBM Rational Test RealTime for safety critical code C.

Answer (score 2):

They had to define some input data, manually calculate the output, and then check it by running the program. See e.g. the paper [*The 
FORTRAN Automatic Coding System* by Backus et al. (1957)](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102663113.05.01.acc.pdf):

> He then programmed the job in four  hours, using 47 FORTRAN  statements.
>   These were  compiled by the 704 in six minutes, producing about 1000 instructions.
>   He ran the program and found the output incorrect.
>   He studied the output ... and was able to localize his error in a FORTRAN statement he had written.
>   He rewrote  the offending statement, recompiled, and found that the resulting program was correct.